# Custom Editors in an Ext.js Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, extjs, extjs4

So this is my first time posting here but I'm more or less stumped. Basically what I have is an ext grid that loads a bunch of data. Among these columns are all these date fields. Start, Finish, Etc. I'm trying to create a date picker to edit these columns. I've experimented with the different ext component editors and I was able to hack together something that mostly worked but what I would really prefer is a way to use my own custom date picker or even better a third party solution like the JQuery UI date picker.

Neither extending nor overriding the editor seemed to do the trick. I'm not so much looking for code but more whether this is even possible with ext and if so maybe to be pointed in the right direction. So has anyone ran into a similar problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using the built in Ext date picker?

Comment: its something mandated from the top down. they just want ext for the grid and store. Where possible they would prefer to use there own custom components or at least ones they choose because ext doesn't really work all that well with well anything

Comment: I'd say you're going to have a pretty hard time of it. Ext doesn't really "play" with other frameworks because it's for building apps, it's not in a space like jquery where you take bits and pieces and mash them all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that it would be fairly straight forward to extend Ext.form.field.Picker and use the jQuery date picker as the picker part.  I've wrapped the FCK editor in an Ext component and it was very easy to do.  Picker involves a few more moving parts, but I think it's worth a try.

That being said, the idea of picking a few parts of ExtJS to use in a non-Ext app and then trying to marry other things into Ext is going to be painful.  I strongly advise fully embracing ExtJS and then choosing very carefully where you stray away.  Another approach might be to use a different grid system (sorry Evan) that plays nicer with jQuery.